# Scrolling animation code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am an absolute newbie to jquery and here is one of my first scripts , its basically suppose to add an animation basically when scrolling to a particular, section , the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taujw84h/).

the scrolling code that i have in jquery is :

```
$('nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $('nav a').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                })
                $(this).addClass('active');

                var target = this.hash,
                   menu = target;
                $target = $(target);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                });
            });
```

now i only know basic debugging in JS and so the only fault i could find in the script is that `target` is not defined. i got this script from an online tut and it worked perfectly over there , but i have no idea why here its not working.

i can't understand the authors intent of adding an undefined variable .

can somebody please point me out what am i doing wrong ? original Tutorial code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/).

TY . 
Alex-z

Comment: @everyone , this also in my 100th question on SO , so please upvote me , common guys ... its an achievement ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of animating `html, body`, you probably want to animate `.content`:

```
$('.content').animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 500, 'swing', function () {
   window.location.hash = target;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvg4zxry/)

---

In this code:

```
var target = this.hash,
```

… `this` refers to the `a` element that was clicked, and `hash` refers to its URL.

So for this element:

```
<a href="#ex-1">Example-1</a>
```

… `this.hash` would be `#ex-1`.

---

This code:

```
$target = $(target);
```

… is now equivalent to:

```
$target = $('#ex-1');
```

… which refers to the `div` with that `id`.

---

`.content` is then scrolled to that `div`'s top position.

Comment: @RickHitchcork ! thanks genious ! .. one last question , what is target and where is it coming from ? :) .............. +1 anyways .